# How to exclude commits from master to another branch

Tags: git

Some of our developers have commited non working commits on the master. I would like to clean it, so that every commit on the master is a working version.

Assume we have the following commits:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F
```

How to extract one or more commits to another branch:

```
A - B           E - F
      \       /
        C - D
```

Edit:

- Commit C and D should be removed.

Comment: Do you want to also remove commits `C` and `D` from the `master` branch, or do you only want to "extract" them to another branch?

Comment: Do you realize that if you remove commits `C` and `D` from the remote `master` branch that many developers might be forced to delete their local branch and pull from scratch?

Comment: Yes, but our workflow tolerates such behavior once in a while.

Comment: `git rebase --onto B D F` and `git push -f <remote> HEAD:<branch>` if you want to update the remote repo.

Answer (score 2):

Execute:

```
git rebase -i B
```

Then you can pick and choose from the commits that were introduced since B.

The `-i` flag stands for *interactive*, which means an editor will show up (it's `vi` by default, just like when editing a commit message) with a list of commits in each line. You can remove a line to skip commit, replace order of the commits or even combine two or more commits into a single commit.

More information could be found in chapter [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) of the official git documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be able to tolerate rewriting the history of the `master` branch despite it being public (and probably in use by many developers), you can consider the following strategy:

- `git cherry-pick` the `C` and `D` commit into a new branch, in that order
- `git rebase --interactive` the `master` branch to remove the `C` and `D` commits

First cherry pick the `C` and `D` commits into a new branch:

```
git checkout new_branch
git cherry-pick dk8cnj2
git cherry-pick dn52bd6
```

Here, the funny-looking strings after `cherry-pick` are actually the SHA-1 hashes of the `C` and `D` commits, q.v. below.  This is how you tell Git to refer to an actual commit.

Now that you have salvaged the `C` and `D` commits, you can start an interactive rebase to remove them from the `master` branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

This should bring up an editor showing you a list of the most recent 4 commits (cf. `HEAD~4`) like the following, in order of oldest to newest:

```
pick dk8cnj2 Commit C
pick dn52bd6 Commit D
pick 9m38b2f Commit E
pick ldkj093 Commit F
```

*Remove* (i.e. delete) the lines for commits `C` and `D`, leaving you with the following in the editor:

```
pick 9m38b2f Commit E
pick ldkj093 Commit F
```

Then save the file, close it, and continue the rebase.  After this, you will have effectively spliced out the `C` and `D` commits from your `master` branch.   Now, since you did this locally, and since you also rewrote the history of `master`, you will have to force push it to the repository:

```
git push --force origin
```

Keep in mind that this will *rewrite* the history of the `master` branch, would could cause confusion for anyone else who is working with that branch.  One way to cope with this would be to tell everyone to freeze work on `master` at the end of the day, after which you complete the interactive rebase.  The next morning have everyone delete their local `master` and checkout a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution of the interactive rebase given by TMG is to create a temporary branch on master, reset master to commit B and cherry-pick all commit you need to keep.

It give you these commands. WARNING : Be sure to not have current changes, or stash them.

```
// Starting point
git checkout master
// Create a new branch to avoid loosing some commit
git branch tmp
// Change master HEAD
git reset --hard master commit_B
// Get the commits you want
git cherry-pick commit_E
git cherry-pick commit_F
// DONE, you can clean up tmp branch if you don't need commit C and D (you will loose them)
git branch -D tmp
```